Mosaicking Image Collection by Date (day) in Google Earth Engine whith 'properties'
That code is very good. I can mosaic all the images (tiles) in my area.
But my problem is that I lost all the properties in each image list after Mosaicking.
In order to analysis time series, I need to have metadata (properties'):
start = ee.Date('2019-06-01')
finish = ee.Date('2021-06-30')

diff = finish.difference(start, 'day')

range_ = ee.List.sequence(0, diff.subtract(1)).map(lambda day: start.advance(day, 'day'))

def day_mosaics(date, newlist):
    date = ee.Date(date)
    newlist = ee.List(newlist)
    #.set("system:time_start", ee.Date(date).millis())
    filtered = Collection.filterDate(date, date.advance(1, 'day'))
    p=filtered.first().get('properties')
    image = ee.Image(filtered.mosaic().set(p))
    #image = image.set(p)
    
    return ee.List(ee.Algorithms.If(filtered.size(), newlist.add(image), newlist))

newcol = ee.ImageCollection(range_.iterate(day_mosaics, ee.List([])))
print((newcol.getInfo()))



You're attempting to get a property named properties from the image.  There is no such thing.  You can copy all the non-system properties using image.copyProperties, but it's way easier and better to just shove your new bands into the old image container.
image = filtered.first().select().addBands(filtered.mosaic())


but be careful, the footprint is probably no longer valid because you're (probably) mosaicing a larger area, so you might need to reset the geometry too.

You should never use if() or iterate(). Instead, just map over the range (already a list) and make an image collection using collection.fromImages()

